# Instance environment variables

Tags: metadata, google-compute-engine

I have several Google Compute Engine instances, and have set instance metadata on each, under the assumption these are available on the instance itself as an environment variable, but they don't show up.  I then read [here](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/metadata) that I need to query the metadata server for this data, but that just returns a 403 unauthorized when run from the instance itself.  Is there a way to access metadata as environment variables?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It may be worth studying [Metadata querying](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/metadata#querying) a bit more, but my guess is that you are attempting to get *custom* metadata, which is resulting in it not being found. Make sure you are using the `attributes` directory to access any custom metadata.

For example, this will get the built-in `tags` metadata:

```
curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/tags" \
    -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

while this will get your custom metadata for attribute `foo`:

```
curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/<instance|project>/attributes/foo" \
    -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I was under the impression that the metadata I add to a project automatically gets set in the VM instance as environment variables, but it looks like I need to fetch them myself.  I think I may have confused GCE with AWS, where that does happen.

Comment: You might have thought that because some of the meta-data actually DOES get loaded into the instance as an environment variable, and some other actually gets loaded into files. If you'd like to, you could create a start-up script as well as a cron job that pulls in all meta-data by key => value and sets environment variables the same way, but some metadata is much bigger than your standard environment variable :)

Comment: With the second command, would you need to replace instance and project with the actual instance and project name? I can't get this to work somehow... I even tried passing in ```Authorization Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)```