# pass metadata to containers command in gce

Tags: metadata, google-compute-engine

I'd like to store an api key (eg:a twitter key) to metadata.
Then use it from the command line of a sub container.

```
#api-keys.yaml:
TWITTER-CONSUMER-KEY: blahah
TWITTER-CONSUMER-SECRET: blihih
```

.

```
#google-container-manifest.yaml:
version: v1beta2
containers:
  - name: tweet-thing-one
    image: gcr.io/my-project/tweetfeed
    command:
     - --consumer-key=$TWITTER-CONSUMER-KEY
     - --consumer-secret=$TWITTER-CONSUMER-SECRET
     - --params-for=one
  - name: tweet-thing-two
    image: gcr.io/my-project/tweetfeed
    command:
     - --consumer-key=$TWITTER-CONSUMER-KEY
     - --consumer-secret=$TWITTER-CONSUMER-SECRET
     - --params-for=two
...
```

So I could run

```
$ gcloud compute instances create containervm-test-1 \
    --image container-vm \
    --metadata-from-file api-keys=api-keys.yaml \
                         google-container-manifest=google-container-manifest.yaml \
    --zone us-central1-a \
    --machine-type f1-micro
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Looks like two separate issues:
(1) the api-keys.yaml file isn't translated into environment variables within the VM; instead, those need to be queried from the metadata server directly.  See e.g. [Instance environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23376214/instance-environment-variables) and  https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/metadata#querying.

(2) If you specify "command:" in the manifest, you need to specify the entire command you want to run, not just the flags.  From https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/container_vms

> containers[].command[]  *list of string* The command line to run. If this is omitted, the container is assumed to have a command embedded in it."

Comment: To add some ideas for solutions:
- include a launcher script in your container that fetches the appropriate keys and extracting them to environment variables, and then have that launcher run your actual program.
> curl -s "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/consumer-key" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"

Comment: Sorry, to add some ideas for solutions:
(1) include a launcher script in your container that fetches the appropriate keys and extracting them to environment variables, and then have that launcher run your actual program.  Set each key in a different value and something like:
> CONSUMERKEY=$(curl -s "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/consumer-key" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google")
(2) pre-process your google-container-manifest.yaml to inject those keys via sed or awk or the like.  Sadly, yaml doesn't have great variable-substitution support natively.

Comment: Hello
1/ Okay so does that mean that I absolutely have to change my code so it reads the metadata ? ( I expected something more, 'scopefree')
2/ The command actually work because my docker image is the command, and It only needs some flags to specify configuration.

I think your Idea of querying the arguments from metada directly in the command line is pretty awesome you should make it an answer so I can tick it ;)

I might write a lib to do that in less words !?